# Play Service 6.5.+ granular dependencies not working correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services, dependency-management

**UPDATE:** As per request, the entire dependency declaration from build.gradle, the list of jars, and the dependencies of the included library projects are listed at the bottom of the quesion.

---

I'm working on a project which uses the location, gcm, ads and identity components of Google Play Services (version 7.0.0).

I've defined them as such in the build.gradle of the app module:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0
```

NOTE: Don't know if it's relevant (I don't expect it to be), but the project also includes two additional library modules, one of which declares a subset of the above as dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
```

Still, after trying to build the app, the dexing fails due to overstepping of the 64k method count limit. I was a bit suspicious of this, since before the fine folk at Google introduced granular dependency management, I used [another, more crude approach, by manually stripping away packages from the play services jar in a gradle build task](https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/d7c91b94214acd936e42). This worked fine, and the 64k method limit was not overstepped.

So now, I begrudgingly introduced multi-dex into the project, was finally able to build an .apk, and take a look at the method count by package, using the [dex-method-counts command line tool](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts), which was brought to my attention in [a post by Jake Wharton concerning the unwieldiness of the Play Services monolith](http://jakewharton.com/play-services-is-a-monolith/).

These are the results:

```
        google: 18687
            ads: 127
                mediation: 96
                    admob: 23
                    customevent: 41
            android: 11873
                gms: 11873
                    actions: 4
                    ads: 387
                        doubleclick: 84
                        identifier: 22
                        mediation: 75
                            admob: 2
                            customevent: 48
                        purchase: 16
                        search: 81
                    analytics: 656
                        ecommerce: 34
                    auth: 78
                    common: 1611
                        api: 409
                        data: 141
                        images: 100
                        internal: 580
                            safeparcel: 76
                    dynamic: 213
                    gcm: 35
                    identity: 86
                        intents: 75
                            model: 41
                    internal: 4914
                    location: 516
                        places: 232
                            ui: 7
                    maps: 2395
                        internal: 822
                        model: 1020
                            internal: 505
                    security: 12
                    tagmanager: 955
            common: 5798
                annotations: 3
                base: 558
                    internal: 11
                collect: 4195
                io: 299
                net: 72
                primitives: 383
                util: 288
                    concurrent: 288
            gson: 889
                annotations: 5
                internal: 485
                    bind: 284
                reflect: 18
                stream: 102
```

TL;DR
**The Play Services are listed as having over 18k methods, and also seem to include some components that I never defined as dependencies in build.gradle (e.g. maps).**

So then, I dexed the components I use, one by one, straight from `android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-<component_name>`, using the approach from Jake Wharton's article referenced above.

The results are as follows:

```
Base:

Read in 3592 method IDs.
<root>: 3592
    : 6
    android: 420
        accounts: 5
        app: 62
        content: 71
            pm: 12
            res: 9
        database: 21
        graphics: 42
            drawable: 21
        net: 11
        os: 102
        support: 56
            v4: 56
                app: 45
                content: 4
                util: 7
        text: 1
        util: 22
        view: 4
        widget: 23
    com: 2831
        google: 2831
            android: 2831
                gms: 2831
                    actions: 4
                    auth: 78
                    common: 1611
                        api: 409
                        data: 141
                        images: 100
                        internal: 580
                            safeparcel: 76
                    dynamic: 213
                    internal: 913
                    security: 12
    java: 324
        io: 25
        lang: 143
            ref: 2
            reflect: 13
        math: 2
        nio: 17
        util: 137
            concurrent: 26
                atomic: 4
                locks: 7
            regex: 6
    org: 11
        json: 11
Overall method count: 3592

---

Location:

Read in 1554 method IDs.
<root>: 1554
    android: 65
        app: 1
        content: 13
        location: 3
        net: 1
        os: 41
        text: 1
        util: 5
    com: 1417
        google: 1417
            android: 1417
                gms: 1417
                    common: 75
                        api: 13
                        data: 8
                        internal: 53
                            safeparcel: 36
                    internal: 833
                    location: 505
                        places: 232
                            ui: 7
                    maps: 4
                        model: 4
    java: 72
        lang: 31
        util: 41
            concurrent: 1
Overall method count: 1554

---

GCM:

Read in 72 method IDs.
<root>: 72
    android: 27
        app: 2
        content: 16
            pm: 1
        os: 8
        util: 1
    com: 24
        google: 24
            android: 24
                gms: 24
                    gcm: 24
    java: 21
        io: 1
        lang: 12
        util: 8
            concurrent: 5
                atomic: 2
Overall method count: 72

---

Ads:

Read in 3878 method IDs.
<root>: 3878
    android: 471
        app: 50
        content: 75
            pm: 5
            res: 7
        database: 13
            sqlite: 7
        graphics: 12
            drawable: 1
        location: 4
        media: 5
        net: 25
        os: 67
        provider: 1
        telephony: 3
        text: 2
        util: 16
        view: 67
        webkit: 64
        widget: 67
    com: 3059
        google: 3059
            ads: 127
                mediation: 96
                    admob: 23
                    customevent: 41
            android: 2932
                gms: 2932
                    ads: 353
                        doubleclick: 84
                        mediation: 75
                            admob: 2
                            customevent: 48
                        purchase: 16
                        search: 81
                    analytics: 2
                    common: 39
                        internal: 37
                            safeparcel: 27
                    dynamic: 5
                    internal: 2533
    java: 318
        io: 16
        lang: 126
            ref: 2
            reflect: 3
        math: 7
        net: 23
        security: 11
            spec: 1
        text: 2
        util: 133
            concurrent: 28
                atomic: 7
    org: 30
        json: 30
Overall method count: 3878

---

Identity

Read in 179 method IDs.
<root>: 179
    android: 34
        accounts: 1
        app: 2
        content: 5
        os: 23
        text: 1
        util: 2
    com: 135
        google: 135
            android: 135
                gms: 135
                    common: 28
                        api: 4
                        internal: 21
                            safeparcel: 15
                    identity: 75
                        intents: 75
                            model: 41
                    internal: 32
    java: 10
        lang: 6
        util: 4
Overall method count: 179

TOTAL: 9275
```

TL;DR
**The total method counts for all components I use is in fact 9275, less than half of what ends up in the .apk produced with the gradle build from the beginning of the question!**

Trying to build the .apk without multi-dex support fails, again overstepping the 64k method limit.

I really have no idea what's going on here, and would appreciate some help. Multi-dex is nice and all, but 8k methods is quite a large buffer for my project alone, and if the granular dependencies worked as expected, I wouldn't have to introduce multi-dex for a long time to come.

**Also, please don't suggest proguard as a solution. It's a band-aid at best, and would not be necessary for debug builds if the dependencies were handled correctly.**

---

**ALL DEPENDENCIES**

From the app itself:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile project(':external_libs:GuJEMSSDK-Android:GuJEMSSDK-Android-library')
    compile project(':external_libs:facebook-android-sdk:facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
}
```

Here's the list of JARs for what it's worth:

```
adjust-android-4.0.2.jar
amazon-in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar
android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar
DistimoSDK.jar
eventbus-2.2.1.jar
FlurryAnalytics_3.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.1.2.jar
MobileAppTracker-3.0.jar
plasma-1.95.0.jar
SKMaps.jar
socialauth-4.3.jar
socialauth-android-3.0.jar
```

And here are the dependencies from the build.gradle scripts of the two included library projects:

```
compile files('libs/videoadsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/openudidandroid.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

Where the second one is Facebook, and has Bolts.jar in its libs directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jared, sorry didn't see your comment until just now. I have several other dependencies, both in build.gradle and as jars, which I'll list tomorrow, as it's the middle of the night here right now :S The reason I only mentioned the Play Services here is that they have the highest method count, and the resulting apk when using granular dependencies doesn't seem to honor this granularity.

Comment: You application is really bloated with dependencies. I can take a look and try to cut a few of them down. How did you get so many? Did you  just start working on this?

Comment: Actually this is not a personal project but a rather large and complex production app with a current install base upwards of a 100k devices. The code base is now 5 years old, but in the past 6 months I've led a massive refactoring and redesign effort, so I know for a fact that It's not bloated, all of the dependencies are in fact used in the production code. That's why I was asking about the Play Services specifically, because their granular dependency management doesn't seem to work as advertised when taking a look at what actually ends up in the .apk.

Comment: You will understand then, why I can't simply hand over the source code for tinkering :)

Comment: I never asked for the source.

Comment: I know you didn't, it was just in jest, since of course the easiest way for someone to help me would be if they could take a look into the specifics of the project. I never prefaced the question with a disclaimer about this being closed source, and you didn't know about it until I commented on it just now

Comment: Have you resolved this yet?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. We had to resort to using multidex, which sucks because it increased the apk build time by ~20 percent on average.